# How to use async with other asynchronous modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, fs

Here is a working test program without async:

```
var fs = require('fs');
function test() {
    var finalResponse = '', response = '';
    function showFinalResponse() {
        console.log(finalResponse);
    }
    function processTheFile(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            finalResponse = 'Could not read the file';
        } else {
            response += data;
            response += '</body></html>';
            finalResponse = response;
        }
        showFinalResponse();
    }
    function readTheFile(exists) {
        if (!exists) {
            finalResponse = 'File does not exist.';
            showFinalResponse();
        } else {
            response += '<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en-US"><head></head><body>';
            fs.readFile('file.txt', 'utf8', processTheFile);
        }
    }
    fs.exists('file.txt', readTheFile);
};
test();
```

Here is my attempt at getting the same program to work with async waterfall.  I'm having trouble with how to pass the callbacks around in the async and the fs calls.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var async = require('async');
function testAsync() {var finalResponse, response = '';
    async.waterfall( [
        function checkIfTheFileExists(done) {
            fs.exists('file.txt', done);
        },
        function readTheFile(err, exists, done) {
            response += '<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en-US"><head></head><body>';
            fs.readFile('file.txt', 'utf8', done);
        },
        function processTheFile(err, data, done) {
            response += data;
            response += '</body></html>';
            finalResponse = response;
            done(null);
        } ],
        function showFinalResponse(err) {
            if (err) {
                if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {  // intended to test for file is missing.
                    finalResponse = 'File does not exist.';
                } else { // any other errors.
                    finalResponse = 'Could not read the file';
                }
                console.log(err);
            }
            console.log(finalResponse);
        }
    );
}
testAsync()
```

I can't get the async version to work.  I'm getting confused with where the callbacks go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fs.exists` is an oddball in that it doesn't provide an error parameter to its callback function.  Instead it only provides a single `exists` parameter that indicates whether the file was found or not.  Presumably, if there was an error, `exists` would be `false`.  As such you need to wrap its callback in your own function so that you can provide a separate error parameter to the `waterfall` callback:

```
async.waterfall( [
    function checkIfFileExists(done) {
        fs.exists('file.txt', function(exists) { done(null, exists); });
    },
    function makeSureFileExists(exists, done) {
    ...
```

Note the warning in [the docs](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback), however, that `fs.exists` shouldn't be used, typically.

Comment: I did see that warning, but I'm using it because I don't want to open the file in some situations.  I just want to know whether it exists.

Comment: Please see my final version in the answer below.  Any issues with it?

Answer (score 1):

```
fs.exists('file.txt', done(null));
```

This calls `done` immediately. You need to pass the actual `done` function to `fs.exists`:

```
fs.exists('file.txt', done);
```

Same for the others.

Comment: @ChrisG.: `fs.exists` takes a callback and passes it an error if there’s an error and `null` if there isn’t. You don’t know whether there’s an error until it has been called back. Passing `done` is the same thing as passing `function (error, result) { done(error, result); }`.

Comment: @ChrisG.: `processFileFile` won’t get an error either. That’s the utility of most of the async functions; if there’s an error in any part of the waterfall, only the final callback will get it, and the ones in between will be skipped.

Comment: Ok, making progress, I think.  Still not working though. I edited the question to show my latest attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final working version (in case it helps anyone else).  Thanks again for your help!

```
var fs         = require('fs');
var async      = require('async');
var addErrParm = function (err, done) {return function(exists) {
    done(err, exists);
}}
function testAsync() {var finalResponse, response = '';
    function checkIfTheFileExists(done) {
        fs.exists('file.txt', addErrParm(null, done));
    }
    function readTheFile(exists, done) {
        if (!exists) {
            done('notFound');
        } else {
            response += '<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en-US"><head></head><body>';
            fs.readFile('file.txt', 'utf8', done);
        }
    }
    function processTheFile(data, done) {
        response += (data || 'The file is empty') + '</body></html>';
        finalResponse = response;
        done(null);
    }
    function showFinalResponse(err) {
        if (err) {
            finalResponse = (err === 'notFound' ? 'File does not exist.' : 'Could not read the file');
        }
        console.log(finalResponse);
    }
    async.waterfall([ checkIfTheFileExists,
                      readTheFile,
                      processTheFile
    ], showFinalResponse);
}
testAsync()
```

So basically, async requires removing the err parameter (first argument) from all functions except the final callback, and it requires adding a callback ('done') as an extra parameter on all functions except the final callback.

Also, if there is no err parameter like with fs.exists, you have to create a function to simulate an err parameter so async can remove it.